# Accumulate value count inside a list of tuples in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, count, iteration

I'm trying to parse a list using a pattern string that indicated types of values (annual and quarterly). I need to accumulate quarter numbers in the resulting output. So far I came up with this:

```
row = [100, 10, 40, 25, 25]
fmt = "aqqqq"
expected = [('a',1,100),('q',1,10),('q',2,40),('q',3,25),('q',4,25)]

count :: Char -> String -> Int
count letter str = length $ filter (== letter) str

split :: String -> [a] -> [(Char, Int, a)]
split fmt row = [(freq, count freq (fmt' i), x)   
               | (freq, x, i) <- zip3 fmt row [0..]]
               where fmt' i = take (i+1) fmt

-- split "aqqqq" [100, 10, 40, 25, 25]
-- [('a',1,100),('q',1,10),('q',2,40),('q',3,25),('q',4,25)]
```

I imagine there should be something more readable and performant that this code, or even a terrific one liner.

I also experimented with expanding `"aqqqq"` into list of tuples `[('a',1),('q',1),('q',2),('q',3),('q',4)]` and later adding values; maybe this is a better way as I would need specify the format once for several rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already have a function `expand` to expand `"aqqqq"` into list of tuples, you can accomplish the rest with `zipWith`:

```
Prelude> zipWith (\(p, ix) x -> (p, ix, x)) (expand fmt) row
[('a',1,100),('q',1,10),('q',2,40),('q',3,25),('q',4,25)]
```

The `expand` function produces tuples of the type `Num t => (Char, t)`. I called the values inside that tuple `p` (for *period*) and `ix` (for *index*). Zipping that list of tuples with `row` also produces values, that I, in the lambda expression, simply called `x`.

Comment: Thank you for `zipWith` suggestion and thorough explanation! I will put together `expand` and `zipWith` in a separate posting for reference.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is how to convert the string, say `"aqqqq"` to the list of frequency of characters appear in the string. i.e. we want:

```
"aqqqq" => [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Once the list of frequency is constructed, we can use `zip3` to product the expected list of tuples as:

```
[('a',1,100),('q',1,10),('q',2,40),('q',3,25),('q',4,25)]
```

Obviously, we can't use `map` to product desired frequency list since the value need to be accumulated. To solve it, I recommend to use `Data.Map` in order to improve the computational complexity from `O(n)` to `O(log n)`.

It is simple to count the frequency using `insertWith` as:

```
countFreq  c m = insertWith (+) c 1 m
```

and get back the accumulated value using `lookup` as:

```
accumValue c m = fromMaybe 0 (Map.lookup c m) + 1
```

now, it is straight forward to build desired list as:

```
mkAccumList (c:cs) m = accumValue c m : mkAccumList cs (countFreq c m)
```

put all together:

```
import Data.Map as Map (empty, lookup, insertWith)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

countFreq  c m = insertWith (+) c 1 m
accumValue c m = fromMaybe 0 (Map.lookup c m) + 1

split::String -> [a] -> [(Char, Int, a)]
split fmt row = zip3 fmt (mkAccumList fmt Map.empty) row
    where mkAccumList (c:cs) m = accumValue c m : mkAccumList cs (countFreq c m)
          mkAccumList [] _ = []
```

To work with infinite list:

```
take 8 $ split (cycle "aqqqq") (cycle [100, 10, 40, 25, 25])
```

gives

```
[('a',1,100),('q',1,10),('q',2,40),('q',3,25),('q',4,25),('a',2,100),('q',5,10),
('q',6,40)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Mark Seemann suggestion, here is a complete listing with a solution. I changed lambda to a named function for a bit more readability and introduced a type for row format.

```
count :: Char -> String -> Int
count letter str = length $ filter (== letter) str

type RowFormat = [Char]
expand :: RowFormat -> [(Char, Int)]
expand pat = [(c, count c (take (i+1) pat)) | (c, i) <- zip pat [0..]]

split' :: RowFormat -> [a] -> [(Char, Int, a)]
split' fmt values = zipWith merge (expand fmt) values
      where merge (freq, period) value = (freq, period, value)
```

The result is as expected:

```
*Main> split' "aqqqq" [100, 10, 40, 25, 25]
[('a',1,100),('q',1,10),('q',2,40),('q',3,25),('q',4,25)]
```

An afterthought - I still expand the format string each time I parse row, probably even currying `parse = split' "aqqqq"` will just delay computation. 
Here is my try to make a dedicated reader function:

```
makeSplitter fmt = \values -> zipWith merge pos values
      where 
        merge (freq, period) value = (freq, period, value)
        pos = expand fmt 
splitRow = makeSplitter "aqqqq" 
a = splitRow [100, 10, 40, 25, 25]
```

`a` is expected result, same as above

```
[('a',1,100),('q',1,10),('q',2,40),('q',3,25),('q',4,25)]
```

Comment: As you say, partial application of your original solution wouldn't make things faster. Your last definition of `makeSplitter` is good. If you like, you can make the `values` lamdba implicit here: `makeSplitter fmt = zipWith merge pos where ...`. I think it's also clearer what's going on if you just get rid of the `pos` binding: `makeSplitter fmt = zipWith merge (expand fmt) where ...`

Comment: Thank you, @amalloy. I think the excessive bindings I used are due to imperative programming background, I removed them from code.